# The scroolbar is doesn't work in a tkinter app for an window

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, scrollbar

I have a tkinker window with several buttons and layouts that use place. I tried to create a scrollbar to the entire window. I added a scroolbar for a window with grid . The scroolbar doesn't scrool. I don't understand what is wrong. This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
...
def get_text():
    ...
    m=len(obj_list) if len(obj_list)>m else m
    for i in range(m):
        try:
            guidelines = tk.Label(window, text="{0} : {1} ore ({2} ore si {3} minute )".format(obj_list[i].name,'%.2f'%obj_list[i].nr_ore, int(obj_list[i].nr_ore),int((obj_list[i].nr_ore-int(obj_list[i].nr_ore))*60)+1), fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
            guidelines.grid(row=7+i, column=0, sticky='nsew')
            guidelines.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, a=obj_list[i].data,b=obj_list[i].nr_in,c=obj_list[i].nr_out: show_guide_lines(a,b,c))
        except:
            guidelines = tk.Label(window, text='')
            guidelines.grid(row=7+i, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    frame=tk.Frame(window, width=500, height=10+len(obj_list))
           
def show_guide_lines(data_list,nrIn_list,nrOut_list):
    window_guide_lines = tk.Toplevel(window)
    window_guide_lines.title('')
    window_guide_lines.geometry('400x200')
    txt = ''
    for a,b,c in zip(data_list,nrIn_list,nrOut_list) :
        txt=txt+'\n'+'{0}/{1}/{2} : {3} intrari, {4} iesiri'.format(a.day,a.month,a.year,b,c)
    tk.Label(window_guide_lines, text=txt).pack()

    window_guide_lines.tkraise()
    window_guide_lines.focus_force()

mFrame = tk.Tk()
mFrame.geometry("1300x775")
mFrame.configure(background="Gray")
mFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

frame_canvas = tk.Frame(mFrame)
frame_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

Can1 = tk.Canvas(frame_canvas, width=500, height=500)
Can1.grid(row=0, column=0)

vsbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame_canvas, orient="vertical", command=Can1.yview)
vsbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
Can1.configure(yscrollcommand=vsbar.set)

window = tk.Frame(Can1)
Can1.create_window((0,0), window=window,anchor='nw')


#window=tk.Tk()
#window.title('Calculare numar de ore')
#window.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
##Scrollbar-ul




frame=tk.Frame(window, width=500, height=30)
frame.grid(row=0,column=0)



#Butonul de inserare a fisierelor excel
button=tk.Button(text='Insert Excel File', command=getExcel)
button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
label1=tk.Label(window, text="", font=('Calibri 9'))
label1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='nsew')
label2=tk.Label(window, text="Introduceti persoana:", font=('Calibri 11'))
label2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='nsew')
text=tk.Text(window, height=1)
text.grid(row=4, column=0)
#Butonul de executie de dupa introducerea textului
get_button=tk.Button(window, text='Calculeaza', command=get_text)
get_button.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='nsew')
label3=tk.Label(window, text="", font=('Calibri 15'))
label3.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky='nsew')


window.mainloop()  
mFrame.mainloop()
```

The scroolbar looks:[image]

and it doesn't work. It should work but the scrrolbar doesn't scroll. Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Your code can't be run (several undefined objets, like obj_list, get_excel); that said, 2 mainloop() is one too many.

Comment: You need to update the *`scrollregion`* option of the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the *scrollregion* option of `Can1` whenever items are added to `window` frame by binding the event `<Configure>` to `window` frame:

```py
window.bind("<Configure>", lambda e:Can1.config(scrollregion=Can1.bbox("all")))
```